# Convert List of List of String to List of List of Int

Tags: haskell

I have the following list

```
Prelude> let a = [["1676","17348","10"],["1677","18831","10"],["1677","18896","10"]]
```

I want to convert it to list of list of Int like this `[[1676,17348,10],[1677,18831,10],[1677,18896,10]]`

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
f :: [[String]] -> [[Int]]
f [x] = map read (map read x)
```

Comment: @DanielFischer can you explain this briefly ? How does this work?

Comment: One way to see `map` is that it takes a function and lift it to work on lists (in other words : `map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`) so obviously, if you want to work on lists of lists, you have to take a function that already works on lists and lift it with `map` and here, this inner function should transform lists of `String` into lists of `Int`, in other words it should `read` every `String` to an `Int`, so it should lift `read` to work on lists, i.e. `map read`. Putting it together you `map (map read)` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `map (map read)` works.

The inner `(map read)` signature is `[String] -> [Int]`. So it will convert a list of `String` to list of `Int`. Now to apply it to list of list of `String`, you only have to raise it using `map`, hence `map(map read)` works. In this you are applying the function `(map read)` to each element on the list of `[String]` (or list of list of `String`, if that makes it better). 
You can not have `map read (map read)`, because the type signature of `read` is `String -> Int`. Your outer `read` type signature `(map`**`read`**`(map read))` is `[String]->[Int]` and that's not how `read` works.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.7.1.2) library (Control.Lens) 3.7.1.2

```
import Control.Lens
f :: [[String]] -> [[Int]]
f = over (traverse.traverse) read
```

Now if instead we had:

```
Prelude> let a = [("1676","17348"),("1677","18831"),("1677","18896")]

f :: [[String]] -> [(Int, Int)]
f = over (traverse.both) read
```

Or for three tuples we would need a new function thrice by expanding from the definition of both.

```
Prelude> let a = [("1676","17348","10"),("1677","18831","10"),("1677","18896","10")]

import Control.Lens
import Control.Applicative

thrice f ~(a, a', a'') = (,,) <$> f a, <*> f a' <*> f a''

f :: [[String]] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
f = over (traverse.thrice) read
```